# Can we call a functional component as Stateful component if it is using react hooks and have state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As I was reading about this and didn't found any satisfactory answers related to the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after 16.8 and with the introduction of hooks, you can manage state in functional components using `useState` and `useReducer`. You can read more about them here -

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html